# Are strings objects?

Tags: javascript

Here are two reasons to think strings are objects. First, you can create a string in the following way:

```
var mystring = new String("asdf");
```

I'm under the impression that the constructor function following the new operator has to return an object. Second, strings seem to have properties and methods. For example:

```
mystring.toUpperCase();
```

BUT, if strings were objects, then we'd expect something like the following to work:

```
function string_constructor() {
    return "asdf";
}

var mystring = new string_constructor();
```

But it doesn't, and I've been told it doesn't because strings aren't objects. So are strings objects or not? And, either way, how can I make sense of everything I've listed?

Comment: Strings are objects in JavaScript

Comment: @mplungjan In the Netherlands we say: short but powerful. But it's an answer, not a comment. ^^

Comment: Thanks. I answered. Langer en krachtiger

Comment: But strings are **not necessarily objects** in JavaScript.  String **constants** in particular are **not** objects - they're values. They are automatically promoted to "String" objects when necessary however.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Speaking about language types, **Strings are [values](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2)** of the String type.

The language has five [**primitive types**](http://es5.github.io/#x8), which are *String*, *Number*, *Boolean*, *Null* and *Undefined*.

There are String objects (also for Number or Boolean), they are called *primitive wrappers*, they are created when you use the constructor function associated with them, for example:

```
typeof new String('foo'); // "object"
typeof 'foo';             // "string"
```

But don't get confused with them, you will *rarely need* to use primitive wrappers, because even if primitive values are not objects, you can still access their inherited properties, for example, on a string, you can access all members of `String.prototype`, e.g.:

```
'foo'.indexOf('o'); // 2
```

That's because the property accessor (the dot in this case) temporarily converts the primitive value to an object, for being able to resolve the `indexOf` property up in the prototype chain.

About the constructor function you have in your question, as you know, it won't return the string.

Functions called with the `new` operator return an implicit value, which is a new object that inherits from that function's `prototype`, for example:

```
function Test () {
  // don't return anything (equivalent to returning undefined)
}

new Test() instanceof Test; // true, an object
```

If an **object** is returned from the constructor, that newly created object (this within the constructor) will be lost, so the explicit returned object will come out the function:

```
function Test2() {
  return {foo: 'bar'};
}

new Test2().foo; // 'bar'
```

But in the case of *primitive values*, they are *just ignored*, and the new object from the constructor is implicitly returned (for more details check the [`[[Construct]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) internal operation, (see step 9 and 10)).

Comment: In JavaScript, the language type names are capitalized. The 5 primitive types are: Number, String, Boolean, Null and Undefined.

Comment: You say: Strings are values. But you have to say of which type also. Every value is of a type.

Comment: @Šime: Yep, clarified it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, strings come in two flavors:

1. There is a String language type which contains values like `"foo"` and `'bar'`. Those values are primitive values. [**Read about the String type here**](http://es5.github.com/#x8.4)
2. Then there is a String constructor. (A constructor is a function object which is used to create new instances of a certain "class" (or pseudo-class)). So this: `new String("foo")`
   will create a new object (a value of the type Object), which contains the primitive value "foo". [**Read about the String constructor here**](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5)

In practice you don't use the `new String('foo')` notation, but the string literal notation `'foo'`.

---

## So to answer your question:

In JavaScript, strings are not objects. They are primitive values. However, there exist String objects which can be used to store string values, but those String objects are not used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive strings behaves like objects in JavaScript because they are automatically converted to objects when you call an object method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

> String objects may be created by
>   calling the constructor new String().
>   The String object wraps JavaScript's
>   string primitive data type with the
>   methods described below. The global
>   function String() can also be called
>   without new in front to create a
>   primitive string. String literals in
>   JavaScript are primitive strings.
>
> Because JavaScript automatically
>   converts between string primitives and
>   String objects, you can call any of
>   the methods of the String object on a
>   string primitive. JavaScript
>   automatically converts the string
>   primitive to a temporary String
>   object, calls the method, then
>   discards the temporary String object.
>   For example, you can use the
>   String.length property on a string
>   primitive created from a string
>   literal

Comment: your answer contradicts itself... "Strings are for sure objects in JavaScript:" ... "String literals in JavaScript are primitive strings."

Comment: Already fixed - I should have said: for sure BEHAVES like objects BECAUSE - sheez people are so harsh here.

Comment: That does not answer the question. the question is: "Are strings objects?". You answer implies that strings are not objects, but you have to make that clear.

Comment: Okeee. So +1 for your answer. At least I posted the URL to the horse's mouth - no-one else did so far

Answer (score 0):

String are both primitive and object type. Think about int, float, char ... which have real Object classes like Integer, Float and Char in Java.

Answer (score 0):

String is a wrapper around the primitive string datatype. When you do something like `var s = "My String"` then a String wrapper object is created behind the scenes when needed..

It is interesting however that `typeof s` = 'string' instead of 'object'. Anybody know why that is?

Comment: The "String" wrapper object is only created when it has to be - it's not created by simple assignment of a string constant to a variable.

Comment: Because `s` is a value of the type String, and not a value of the type Object (obviously). Don't bother with the String object wrapper. It is not used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are objects, but what you are doing in your example is not creating a new String. By using 'new' you are creating an instance of a Object, not a 'string'

```
var F = function() {
    return 'c';
};
var a = new String('a');
var b = 'b';
var c  = new F();
alert("a is: " + typeof a + ", b is: " + typeof b + ", c is: " + typeof c);
// alerts: a is: object, b is: string. c is: object
```

You shouldn't use 'new' for strings regardless (or arrays, or 'simple' objects.)

Comment: You say strings are objects, but your demo shows that the variable `b` is a string and not an objects (which contradicts your initial statement).

Comment: Semantics have got me again! A String is an object of type 'string', whereas a and b produce objects of type 'object'.