# Question about Javascript properties and instances

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, properties, instances

I can't figure out myself why `foo.bar` in the example is `undefined`, could you explain?

```
var foo = "foo";

foo.bar = "baz";
console.log(foo.bar); // undefined
```

Q2: How do I add references to properties and methods to the `String` instance `foo`?

Help is appreciated, thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

Note: the question is about a generic String *instance*, not the [String global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). So using "classic" prototyping as someone suggested is not an option, because this way every String instance would have a property called `bar`, while I want to augment only certain *instances*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript).

Basically, you're creating a string, and this is a primitive type in javascript.

**You cannot add properties to primitive types in javascript**.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.bar = "baz";` is the same as `undefined = "baz";`

You can add functions to string by using it's prototype;

```
String.prototype.bar = function() {
    return "baz";
};

foo.bar() ; //# => baz
```

Answer (score 2):

By using a real String object for `foo`:

```
var foo = new String('foo');
foo.bar = 'baz';
console.log(foo.bar); // 'baz'
```

Comment: +1 Tested this in rhino and it works. Though `'s' === new String('s')` evaluates to false as they have different types. Sort of thing I could imagine causing bugs.

Comment: Don't know about bugs, I think if it's badly used it can cause bugs. But hey, that's with all code, isn't it? Anyway, it's all doable but I have never found much use for this kind of string-extension, I must say.

Answer (score 1):

When you specified var foo = "foo"; you are asking foo to be interpreted as a string. String can only have a literal as a value. It cannot have any other sub-properties. ( just extend this logic to any other oo programming language you know and it will become clearer). Instead you could do something like this.

```
 var fooObject = new Object()
fooObject.foo = "foo"
fooObject.bar = "baz"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about "prototyping", which is the ability to add custom properties to objects in javascript.

This is an excellent and concise tutorial on prototyping:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml

Answer (score 0):

To extend the String class, modify its prototype:

```
String.prototype.bar = "baz";
var foo = "foo";
console.log(foo); // "foo"
console.log(foo.bar); // "baz"
```

In your question, you were modifying an instance of the String class instead of the String class itself.