# Why does ("foo" === new String("foo")) evaluate to false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, equality

I was going to start using === (triple equals, strict comparison) all the time when comparing string values, but now I find that

```
"foo" === new String("foo")
```

is false, and same with this:

```
var f = "foo", g = new String("foo");
f === g; // false
```

Of course:

```
f == g; // true
```

So is it recommended to always use == for string comparison, or always convert variables to strings before comparing?

Comment: Maybe because `foo` is the pure string and `new String("foo")` is the Object String

Comment: Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: It is recommended not to create strings with `new String` (Completely pointless) rather than using `==`

Comment: Why would anybody want to use construct like `new String("foo")` in Javascript in the first place? I've never seen such code in code i.e. jQuery...

Comment: ok so if I'm developing a JS library to be used elsewhere, I can assume and require that a function take a parameter as a primitive string, and if the API user passes a String() object I can assume that's incorrect use of the API

Comment: @MichaelButler: Absolutely, if that's how the API is documented. Require very specific argument types, and you can avoid a bunch of duck typing.

Comment: @MichaelButler: Yes.  There are very few reasons to explicitly create and use boxed primitives.

Comment: I suppose you could use a boxed String object to pass by reference to a function that modifies it. bad practice, but possible.

Comment: @MichaelButler That would be pointless as strings are immutable in JavaScript anyway.

Comment: Actually, that wouldn't even be possible.  You can't really modify a boxed `String` object.

Comment: You can use `String(obj)` to convert a boxed string to the primitive once you've received your "string" parameter. `("foo" === String(new String("foo"))) === true`

Comment: @SLaks, @alpha123: `var s = new String("foo"); s.myprop = 5; alert(s.myprop); // shows 5  alert(s + "bar"); // shows "foobar"`. So I think you **can** modify a boxed String object. Unboxed strings are immutable. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MichaelButler: You can add a property to it, but you can't change the value of the string.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between string literals and String objects in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17256182/1048572)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`"foo"` is a string *primitive*.  (this concept does not exist in C# or Java)

`new String("foo")` is boxed string object.

The `===` operator [behaves differently on primitives and objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6).
When comparing primitives (of the same type), `===` will return true if they both have the same value.

When comparing objects, `===` will return true only if they refer to the same object (comparing by reference).  Thus, `new String("a") !== new String("a")`.

In your case, `===` returns false because the operands are of different types (one is a primitive and the other is an object).

---

Primitives are not objects at all.
The `typeof` operator will not return `"object"` for primitives.

When you try to access a property of a primitive (using it as an object), the Javascript language will box it to an object, creating a new object every time.  This is described in the [specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1).

This is why you cannot put properties on primitives:

```
var x = "a";
x.property = 2;
alert(x.property) //undefined
```

Each time you write `x.property`, a *different* boxed `String` object is created.

Comment: +1 `typeof "foo"; // "string"`, `typeof new String("foo"); // "object"`

Comment: Interesting, I thought strings were objects in JS.

Comment: @ddlshack: Everything can be an object even string if you create in instance of it.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Almost everything. Don't forget about `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Sadly, *(as you know)* `typeof` does return `"object"` for one primitive.

Comment: `if( Object(a) !== a ) { //it's a primitive }`

Comment: @Sarfraz how comes strings have properties and methods if they're not objects?

Comment: @ddlshack a string primitive is converted temporarily into object when you use it like an object

Comment: @ddlshack: See http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1 and my edit.

Comment: @amnotiam: Yep that's odd in lovely language :)

Comment: Java do have primitives / .Net don't

Comment: @devundef: Neither C# nor Java have string _primitives_; in both of those languages, `String` is a normal class (reference type).  In .Net, `String is closer to a primitive; it has special support in IL (for literals) and the GC / memory-model (they're not fixed-size).  Both .Net and Java have primitive numeric types.

Comment: @SLaks but Java string intering leads to some related semantics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Answer (score 34):

Using `===`,

- an Object is never equal to anything except another reference to itself.
- a primitive is equal when compared to another primitive if their type and value are the same.

Comment: `new String("foo") === new String("foo")` is `false` :-P

Answer (score 10):

The `new` word is a criminal here (*as usual*, may I say)...

When you use `new`, you explicitly express your desire to work with *object*. It might be surprising for you, but this:

```
var x = new String('foo');
var y = new String('foo');
x === y;
```

... will give you a mighty `false`. It's simple: compared are not the objects' insides, but the objects' references. And they, of course, are not equal, as two different objects were created.

What you probably want to use is *conversion*:

```
var x = String('foo');
var y = String('foo');
x === y;
```

... and that will give you, as expected, `true` as result, so you can rejoice and prosper with your equal `foos` forever. )

Comment: quick question about using this. You're calling String (a constructor?) without the 'new' keyword. Doesn't this mean you will pollute the scope with any properties assigned within the String constructor? Or does that not happen because the constructor is native code? In other words, suppose the String function contained "this.a = 1;" -- that means your function/object would now have a property a = 1.

Comment: I suppose (but cannot say for sure) each of the 'boxing constructor' functions first checks its context - and if it's not a 'newish one' (i.e., a prototype object), switches to the conversion method right away. In case of String that would be `toString()` method, for example.

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is the pure string and `new String("foo")` is the Object String

Answer (score 2):

From the node.js REPL ("node" on the command-line if installed):

```
> "foo" === new String("foo").valueOf()
true
> "foo" === new String("foo")
false
> typeof "foo"
'string'
> typeof new String("foo")
'object'
> typeof new String("foo").valueOf()
'string'
```

Comment: `typeof` doesn't need to be used like a function, and IIRC new binds to the *first* function call.