# When is a JavaScript String not a string?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does (“foo” === new String(“foo”)) evaluate to false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951906/why-does-foo-new-stringfoo-evaluate-to-false-in-javascript)

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586775/javascript-string-equality-whats-the-correct-way) I caught the advice that it's best to use non type-coercive string comparison, but in Chrome, I discovered something kind of odd:

```
var t1 = String("Hello world!");
var t2 = new String("Hello world!");
var b1 = (t1==t2); // true
var b2 = (t1===t2); // false
```

Is this standard behavior? If so, what are the respective types of t1 and t2? Thanks.

Comment: You can check by using the `typeof` operator. And read the [spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.1) for the full details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String`, called as a function, converts its argument to a `string`. `String`, called as a constructor, creates an object whose prototype is the `String` function. (Check [James's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977606/15055) for the relevant ECMAScript specification section.)

This is indeed confusing.

The two equality operators actually do very different things. From the [ECMA-262, v 5.1 document](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf), `===` does:

> 1. If `Type(x)` is different from `Type(y)`, return `false`.
> 2. If `Type(x)` is `Undefined`, return `true`.
> 3. If `Type(x)` is `Null`, return `true`.
> 4. If `Type(x)` is `Number`, then
>          a. If `x` is `NaN`, return `false`.
>          b. If `y` is `NaN`, return `false`.
>          c. If `x` is the same `Number` value as `y`, return `true`.
>          d. If `x` is `+0` and `y` is `-0`, return `true`.
>          e. If `x` is `-0` and `y` is `+0`, return `true`.
>          f. Return `false`.
> 5. If `Type(x)` is `String`, then return `true` if `x` and `y` are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return `false`.
> 6. If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return `true` if `x` and `y` are both `true` or both `false`; otherwise, return `false`.
> 7. Return `true` if `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Otherwise, return `false`.

Whereas `==` does:

> 1. If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then
>      a. If `Type(x)` is `Undefined`, return `true`.
>      b. If `Type(x)` is `Null`, return `true`.
>      c. If `Type(x)` is `Number`, then
>          i. If `x` is `NaN`, return `false`.
>           ii. If `y` is `NaN`, return `false`.
>           iii. If `x` is the same `Number` value as `y`, return `true`.
>           iv. If `x` is `+0` and `y` is `-0`, return `true`.
>           v. If `x` is `-0` and `y` is `+0`, return `true`.
>           vi. Return `false`.
>      d. If `Type(x)` is `String`, then return `true` if `x` and `y` are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, return `false`.
>      e. If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return `true` if `x` and `y` are both `true` or both `false`. Otherwise, return `false`.
>      f. Return `true` if `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Otherwise, return `false`.
> 2. If `x` is null and `y` is undefined, return `true`.
> 3. If `x` is undefined and `y` is null, return `true`.
> 4. If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`, return the result of the comparison
>      `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 5. If `Type(x)` is `String` and `Type(y)` is `Number`, return the result of the comparison
>      `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 6. If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 7. If `Type(y)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 8. If `Type(x)` is either `String` or `Number` and `Type(y)` is `Object`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)`.
> 9. If `Type(x)` is `Object` and `Type(y)` is either `String` or `Number`, return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`.
> 10. Return `false`.

Note that in the spec, the `Type` of a primitive string object is `String`, whereas the type of any object (including the `String` object) is `Object`.

With `===` the relevant line is `#1`: the `Type` of the objects are different, so `false` is returned.

With `==` the relevant line is `#8`: `x` is a `String` (`"Hello world!"`) and `y` is an `Object` (The `String` object containing the string `"Hello world!"`). Thus the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)` is made. `ToPrimitive` ends up calling the `valueOf` method of the object, or if that method doesn't exist, the `toString` method. In this case, a `String` *object*'s `valueOf` method returns the primitive `string` the object contains. Thus the equality operation is done again, this time between two primitive `string`s which contain the same text, which returns `true` thanks to `#1.d`.

JavaScript is a bit messy under the hood...

---

EDIT: Notice that if two objects are compared, no conversions apply, but rather, rule `#1.f` applies. Thus, thanks to the spec, I was able to correctly predict the output of the following code:

```
> new String("hi") == new String("hi")
false
```

---

EDIT: Just thought I'd add that these distinctions are even further blurred by more implicit type conversion. For example, the following works:

```
> ("hi").toString()
"hi"
```

but that's not because `"hi"` is an object (like in Python):

```
> typeof "hi"
"string"
```

But rather, because the [`.` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) [does a conversion](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1) from the primitive `string` type to the string `Object` type (creating a new string object) whose `toString` method is then called.

Comment: You're missing part of `===`'s 6. and 7., also I think a quote block would be more readable than a code one.

Comment: thanks, but how would i indent the lines? added in missing bits of 6+7

Comment: Good question. +1 for the completion. I'm checking what's the easiest way to indent and keep the numbering.

Comment: Eh guess it's readable enough like this, blockquote looks like a wall of text, least like this it's more colored. `=]` People can always read the formatted version in your link.

Comment: I think the indenting and `code` hinting is correct. Please check.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: thanks, looks pretty good! clever use of `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 9):

If you don't use the "`new`" keyword with String, you get a primitive string.

If you use "`new`" keyword, you get a string object instead of primitive.

When you use **`==`** it will try to convert to a comparable type, so it can be equal.

If you use **`===`**, it won't convert, so an object can not equal a primitive.

Comment: +1 In addition: `String` is a *special* type of object in that has [ToPrimitive] is defined over it. There is no other custom object for which `==` (using the above string values) would be equal.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the explanation

```
typeof String("Hello world!");
"string"
```

And:

```
typeof new String("Hello world!");
"object"
```

when you use `===` it is paying attention to the type so it returns false

Comment: It's not an explanation, but yeah it's showing why they aren't equal. Explnation would be telling why `new String` and `String` create different types.

Comment: True, but you didn't explain why `==` is evaluating `true` while `===` evaluates to `false`. The explanation is that `==` compares values while `===` compares both value and type. One is a string while the other is an object, and that's why `===` is `false`.

Comment: This also doesn't explain why `==` works (there are very few objects for which `==` makes sense in JavaScript) .. just why `===` doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is detailed in the [ECMAScript 5 specification, 15.5.1 and 15.5.2](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.1):

> When `String` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.
>
> ...
>
> Returns a String value (not a `String` object) computed by `ToString(value)`. If `value` is not supplied, the empty String "" is returned.

So `String("some string")` creates a string value.

> When `String` is called as part of a `new` expression, it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.

So `new String("some string")` creates an instance of the `String` object.

---

And to actually answer your questions:

> Is this standard behavior?

*Yes*, for the reasons detailed above.

> If so, what are the respective types of t1 and t2

You can check this with the `typeof` operator:

```
console.log(typeof t1); //string
console.log(typeof t2); //object
```

Comment: +1, also `new String("Hello world!").toString() === String("Hello world!")`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `==` operator only checks if the values are the same, whereas `===` checks both the value **and** type. `new String("Hello world!")` is not actually being given the type `string`, it is an `object`, while `String("Hello world!")` is actually a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example `String("Hello world!)"` creates a primitive string while the second example `new String("Hello world!")` creates an String object.