# What is the difference between a number and a number object?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between a number stored in a normal variable:

```
var foo = 5;
```

And a number object:

```
var bar = new Number(5);
```

What can I use a number object for?

Comment: Could you please post examples. Numbers are numbers, whether they are contained within an object or not.

Comment: I said Object number, like var num = new Number(123);

Comment: Edited the question to clarify...

Comment: Similar, regarding strings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17256340/268093

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `Number` object contains some useful methods and properties such as:

### Number Object Methods

```
Method                       Description
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
toExponential(x)    Converts a number into an exponential notation
toFixed(x)          Formats a number with x numbers of digits after the decimal point
toPrecision(x)      Formats a number to x length
toString()          Converts a Number object to a string
valueOf()           Returns the primitive value of a Number object
```

### Number Object Properties

```
Property                        Description
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
constructor         Returns the function that created the Number object's prototype
MAX_VALUE       Returns the largest number possible in JavaScript
MIN_VALUE           Returns the smallest number possible in JavaScript
NEGATIVE_INFINITY   Represents negative infinity (returned on overflow)
NaN             Represents a "Not-a-Number" value
POSITIVE_INFINITY   Represents infinity (returned on overflow)
prototype           Allows you to add properties and methods to an object
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number MDN Documentation on Number object

Comment: But how does this answer relate to the `new Number(123)` that the OP posted in a comment above? (I know that comment was posted after this answer so it's certainly not your fault FaceOfJock, but now that the question has been clarified this doesn't really answer it.)

Comment: the question have been edited by a moderator ,it's not the op question

Comment: @FaceOfJock The comment came from the OP but it's true that I've edited the question because it was very unclear.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder until now , i think that this is the difference , he needs just to replace x parameter by 123 in the example and test

Comment: In addition to the methods mentioned here, you can attached metadata to the number. Such as: `foo.first = false`. If you attempt to attach this to a plain number the attachment will be silently dropped.

Answer (score 8):

I think in practice there is no difference between this two. All available methods for number objects is also available for primitive numbers. When you invoke a method on a primitive number, the number temporarily gets converted to an object and then the method executes. See the following examples:

```
var temp1 = Object(1) // number object   
var temp2 = 1         // primitive number

console.log(temp1.toString()) // invoke its own method. result: 1
console.log(temp2.toString()) // temporarily converts to object and invoke number object method. result:1

console.log(Object(1).constructor === Number) //true
console.log((1).constructor === Number)       //true
//             ^---------- temporarily converts to object
```

Comment: "*I think in practice there is no difference between this two*" `foo = new Number(5); bar = new Number(5); console.log(foo === bar)` behaves COMPLETELY DIFFERENTLY to `foo = 5; bar = 5;  console.log(foo === bar)` because two different *objects* are not equal, while two number primitives with the same value - are.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = 5; 
typeof(foo); // Is Number

var bar = new Number(5);
typeof(bar); // Is object
```

When you go down to advanced level in JavaScript, you have certain properties for objects which you can't invoke on numbers, so it is up to you to draw a line and see what to use where.

> **Numbers** – e.g. 5, 3e+10 (all numbers behave as floats – significant
>   for division, but can be truncated by x >>> 0). Sometimes boxed.
>   *Instance of Number when boxed*.
>
> **Objects** – e.g. {foo: 'bar', bif: [1, 2]}, which are really just
>   hashtables. Always boxed. *Instance of Object.*

Comment: _" advanced level in JavaScript, you have certain properties for objects which you can't invoke on numbers"_ - Could you please give an example or two?