# Is String an instance of the object String()?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript and there is something that I don't understand.

```
//This means that I am using a method from the String.prototype
"ThisIsMyString".length
```

So, if I use ("ThisIsMyString" instanceof String) was suppose to return true, wasn't it? But turns out that returns false.. and I belive that is because the primitive type.

Here is my question: If "ThisIsMyString" is not an instance of String, how it can access property from that Object? What's the part of the puzzle that I don't know?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/javascript-string-literal-vs-string-object

Comment: Be careful with terms: Javascript has no "primitive types", but it has "literals" (as most languages). They are not considered separate types however but language constructs that don't really fit the OO model.

Comment: @JohannesH. Not quite... [§4.3.2 primitive value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: oh. ok, well then ;) I have to admit, I never read the spec, but most references only use the term literals, that'S why I was under the impression that it is the only term used here. Doesn't mka too much difference though ^^

Comment: @JohannesH. Yeah. "*Literals*" just refers to the syntax involved ([§7.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8)), which most do create primitive values at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

String.length is not

> a method from the String.prototype

`length` is a **property** of String

[See the MDN docs for String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

---

To answer your question though, the reason `"hello" instanceof String` returns false lies within how [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) actualy works

```
Object.getPrototypeOf("hello")
// TypeError: Object.getPrototypeOf called on non-object
```

However, this is how your string literal has access to these methods/properties

```
"my string".constructor === String
// true

"my string".__proto__ === String.prototype
// true
```

If you want an actual instance of `String`

```
var str = new String("hello");
str instanceof String
// true
```

Comment: The facts that `"my string".constructor === String` and `"my string".__proto__ === String.prototype` are not the answer, but part of the same behaviour. The reason is the dot operator, which converts a string literal temporarily into a String object to perform the desired operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use such methods because the language recognizes and converts the primitive type to a temporary instance of the `String` object and returns the `length` property of that object.

Comment: Just in case you noticed: Downvoted your initialy response, as it just wasn't true. Better now ;)

Comment: @JohannesH. haha no worries!  You were more than right to down vote me before I fixed my silliness.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html:
"JavaScript implicitly wraps the string primitive in a String object, processes the String object property or method call, and then discards the object"

Read further for details.