# Uncaught TypeError: Object function () exception thrown in console.log

Tags: javascript

Exception thrown on console. Why this exception is been thrown? After this exception is thrown, onchange dropdown does not work anymore. What can I do to prevent this from happening

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (this instanceof String) {
        if (this.indexOf("%") != -1) {
            return this;
        }
    }
    return this + "px";
} has no method 'push'
```

Method in Javascript

```
Object.prototype.measurement = function() {
    if (this instanceof String) {
        if (this.indexOf("%") != -1) {
            return this;
        }
    }
    return this + "px";
};
```

[Link to code](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ULNrC/)

Comment: There's no mention of a `push` method being called in your code, so it's not possible to answer your question without the rest of the code.

Comment: You're doing a push into an object.

Comment: No. This is from chrome console. Updated with link to code.

Comment: Careful: `'' instanceof String // false`. Use `typeof` instead.

Comment: It's just a tip. String literals are not instances of the String constructor.

Comment: @elclanrs Oh, there are no parent for string literals? How does the string methods work on them, then?

Comment: @thefourtheye: String literals are primitives, while a string instance `new String('asdasd')` is an object. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/javascript-string-literal-vs-string-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing function definition from

```
Object.prototype.measurement = function() {}
```

to

```
function measurement(position) {}
```