# Angular $watchGroup issue

Tags: angularjs

I cannot understand why my `oldValue` in `$watchGroup` is not updated.

I have simply code:

```
$scope.sort='date'
$scope.results = [];

$scope.click = function(){
  $scope.sort = 'name'
  $scope.order = !$scope.order
}

$scope.$watchGroup(['sort','order'],function(newVal,oldVal){
  $scope.results.push(newVal[0]+' '+oldVal[0]+'; ' +newVal[1] + ' ' + oldVal[1])
  console.log(newVal[0],oldVal[0],newVal[1],oldVal[1]);
});
```

I'm setting `sort` at the beggining to `'date'` then with button click I change it to `'name'`. Every click changes the value to `'name'`,  but `$watchGroup` says the old value is still `'date'`. The old `order` value is updated, but old `sort` value is not.

Can someone explain this strange behavior?

There is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qpBp00tndmKqBarnfAgN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, because the string literal `name` that you use, is the same one every time you assign it, so `$scope.sort` only changes the first time you click the button. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript)).

If you change your code to `$scope.sort = new String('name')`, you will see the behavior you expected, because that way you always create a new object, and your variable will point to a different place in the memory each time you click.