# Assigning a variable and make use of dom property, not behaving as I expected in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

I'm trying to assign a value to the document with a variable, but when I use the variable for the second time, it resets what I assigned first. Can someone with a comprehensive explanation bring facts to light (not only answer but help comprehend) ?

```
 <script>
  var dataOnly = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  dataOnly = "gray"; //see it assigns a new value, is there another way around?
 </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the background Color of the body to gray?

Comment: Yes, but just as an example code. What I really want to do is assign a data to the document object, with a variable why does that seems impossible. In the sense that this is not the right way to do it in JS (to reuse var) ?

Comment: Try something setting `dataOnly = "gray";` first, then doing `document.body.style.backgroundColor = dataOnly;`. Your example above is just storing the current background color into a variable `dataOnly` then changing the value of that variable, which doesn't do anything to the background Color. Does that make sense?

Comment: I perfectly understand that method, which imply that it's impossible to reuse variables.

Comment: Can I do the same thing similarly with object literal (and yet as a var)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're referring to is values versus references and how assignment and mutation are handled.

I think you may find this an interesting read: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

There is a difference between reassigning a variable's value and accessing a reference "through" a variable:

```
var a = {}
var b = a
b.test = 'test';
console.log(a, b); // these will both be: {'test': 'test'}

var a = 'test1';
var b = a;
b = 'test2';
console.log(a, b); // these will be: 'test1', 'test2'
```

And in your example, had you done:

```
var dataOnly = document.body.style;
dataOnly.backgroundColor = 'gray';
```

I think it would work how you expect.

Comment: This also works and behaves more adequate to what I expect:
[code](var a={b:document.body.style,c:function(x){return this.b.backgroundColor=x}};
a.c("purple");)

Comment: @user2887761 In case it is helpful as it seems you're goal is learning JS, rewriting as something like: `function c(x){ this.backgroundColor = x; } c.bind(document.body.style)('purple');` works as well.

Comment: I was just wondering if I could neutralize the variable from firing, in case of a function inside the variable. So I could reuse it in different scenarios like?`function c(x){ this.backgroundColor = x; } /*notice this variable fires with the function*/ var z = c.bind(document.body.style)('black');`

Comment: @user2887761 If I'm understanding correctly, you could do `var z = c.bind(document.body.style); /* this sets "z" to be "c" with "this" bound to "document.body.style" */ z('black'); z('purple');`

Comment: For the sake of my question first intention, I been trying to do this (with a variable):`var d="black";
if (d===new String("black")){document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue"}` although I can't get it to work, why?

Comment: @user2887761 This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript . The strict equality (`===`) here will not work since `d` will be a `string` but `new String` will be an `object` (not the same type). `typeof` may also be of interest to you.

Comment: Okay, how about refreshing a variable through console.log, or refreshing the variable with new value will not happen in console.log, because JS is static?

Answer (score 0):

So when you type "color"(the variable) after this code entry in the console.log, it will change the background color accordingly to the color specified after assigning(=) it as a string(" " or ' ') inside the variable. And the background will change color in confirmation if it was done correctly(written as a string and right spelling inside the variable color), if it's a hexadecimal with the "#"(symbol in front) and also followed by six numbers or letters (or both mixed together should work too), just note that the letters accepted as hex are: A,B,C,D,E,F (or alternatively a, b, c, d, e, f). Certify that if the color is not hex, it must have the name among the 140 colors supported by modern browsers, for example:gray,purple,black.

```
var color;
setInterval(function(){if (color){document.body.style.backgroundColor=color};},100);
```