# In Javascript is an String literal an object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, language-concepts

I'm reading about the difference between String literal and String objects. See
[What is the difference between string literals and String objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript)

But I'm a bit confuse because there it's explained that you can use methods of the String Objects but technically is a String literal an String Object? I'm not asking if we can use the same methods, only if a String literal is an object. Thanks!

Comment: NO, string is not object, but for consistency, Javascript lets us use it as if it is an Object. When invoking a method on string it is boxed in String object.

Answer (score 3):

The term "string literal" refers to a syntactic convention for representing string values directly in code.

The code

```
"Hello Everyone"
```

is a string literal for a string with 14 characters.

The value *represented by* a string literal is a string primitive. It is not an object. That's why if you use:

```
typeof "Hello Everyone"
```

this will return the value `"string"`, not `"object"`.

JavaScript allows [boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing) of any string primitive to promote them to string objects under certain circumstances. Attempting to call a method on a string value is one of these circumstances. So if you call:

```
"Hello Everyone".toUpperCase()
```

the value represented by this literal will be boxed into a string Object, and the method will be called on that object.

Comment: thank you very much for the clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of a Javascript variable with the `typeof` operator. `typeof "Hello World"` and `typeof String("Hello World")` both return the type "string".

Also, a strict-equal check `"Hello" === String("Hello")` returns true, which means that they are not just value-equal but type-equal.

However, `typeof new String("Hello World")` returns "object".