# Why does " new String('my string'); " return an object? But " String('my string'); " returns a string

Tags: javascript

The code below will return an object:

```
alert(typeof new String("my string"));
```

but it will return string when new is removed:

```
alert(typeof String("my string"));
```

Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects):

> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without using the new keyword) are primitive strings.

When called without new, it returns a string primitive which has type "string" in Javascript. With new it returns a String object.

In most cases they're interchangeable, 
 for example if you access a property of a string primitive it is automatically converted to a String object.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a `constructor` function to create instances of the `String`(which is an `object`).

The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

[More about new here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

and calling those constructor function with out new, is like **casting** ,

so even if you call `String(1);`
you will get `"1"` **(typeof is string here(primitive type) )**

Answer (score 0):

The "new" keyword invokes the String class, meaning you have just created a new String object, which is why your code returns object. Without the `new`, you are simply converting your inner object to a String. (See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp for more info on type conversions)

Answer (score 0):

`String("my string")` is going to **typecast** the value inside it to string, while `new String("my string")` is going to return a new object due [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

New operator will invoke constructor of Object type (String in this case) and create an instance of this object.

Answer (score 0):

String literals like `"something"` and `String("something")` are considered primitive types. However, when using the `new` keyword, a reference to that string is created like an object. You can get around this problem by using the `instanceof` keyword. For example:

```
var something = new String("something");

if ((typeof something === "string") || (something instanceof String))
    console.log("Its a string!");
```