# Why do commas not work to include strings in WriteLine?

Tags: c#, string, console.writeline

I am wondering why a '+' is needed in a scenario like this:

```
string name = "Rick";
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
```

I was under the impression that the '+' was needed to include a variable of another type, and a string could be included without one. Is this incorrect?

Further, if that is the case, then why does it simply skip the variable and not return an error in a situation like this:

```
string name = "Rick";
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " , name);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}" , name);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned, the second version is trying to pass a second parameter, which the `WriteLine` method is not overloaded for. The options you really have for this are as follows

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hello, {0}", name));
```

Comment: `WriteLine()` does have an appropriate overload, making the call to `Format()` unnecessary

Comment: Ah right you are, though as the OP seems to be unsure about string concatenation so it might be worth leaving it in in case he didn't know of its existence :)

Comment: Thank you. I got confused because I remember using your third example earlier but forgot about the needed {#}.

Answer (score 2):

C# concatenates string using operator `+`. So, one strings adds to another string creating third string containing first and second strings. Comma does not concatenate strings, comma separates parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The first Example:

```
string name = "Rick"; //string variable
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
```

the `+` operator is used to concatenate the value of string variable `name` and the string literal `"Hello, "`.

The resulting output will be `Hello, Rick`

For more see:[String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

The second example:

```
string name = "Rick";
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " , name);
```

Matches the overload
[Console.WriteLine(String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx)

It requires the use of a formatter `{0}` because the formatter is not present nothing will happen with the second argument `Object` (in your case in the variable `name`). A proper version of this would be written as :

`string name = "Rick";
Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);`

The object is cast to string and creates a new string with the value of name replacing the `{0}` value. 

The resulting output that is written to screen would be:`Hello, Rick`

For more info I'd recommend you look at the following:

[Console.WriteLine(String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx)

[String Concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

[On String Formatters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Literals vs Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused.  in your first example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
```

the two strings are being concatenated, and the result is being passed as a parameter to the `Console.WriteLine` method.

---

The second example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " , name);
```

is actually calling [a different overload of that method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf(v=vs.110).aspx), that accepts a string and an object.