# How to mock string functions in Javascript and qUnit

Tags: javascript, qunit

Mocking normal functions of objects works usually like this:

```
objToMock.funcToMock = function (param1, ...) {
    equal(param1, 'expectedValue', 'param1 passed correctly');
}
```

If I try this with a native string function, an error wis thrown:

```
var name = 'test_string';
name.split = function (limiter) {
    ok(true, 'split called');
}
```

error:

```
Source: TypeError: Cannot create property 'split' on string 'test_string'
```

Is there a blocking mechanism for built-in string functions? I thought strings are also objects with functions.
Accessing the prototype of 'test_string' does not work, as 'prototype' is undefined.

Searching the web/stackoverflow is quite hard as "javascript", "string", "split" and "mock" are too generic search values.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hint: the `prototype` is defined on the `constructor`, not on the `instance`. and take a look at this: `var name = Object('test_string')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the string literal is an independent type, it's different from Object. In javascript, you can only assign an value for key to an Object.

When you call 'string'.split, the string will be transformed to String Object in the behind. So, your assign is useless.

If you've declared your code in strict mode, the assignment will cause your error.

You may change your code like this:

```
var name = new String('test_string');
name.split = function (limiter) {
    ok(true, 'split called');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me, too.
There was a follow up issue as the main method for the unit-test checks provided name-input with "typeof" which does not work with the String object. A doublecheck with "(typeof name === 'string' || name instanceof String)" did the trick.

Comment: But, `new String('test_string')` and `'test_string'` will give you the same string... how does this help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox In Javascript,  string and string object is different, you can use Object.prototype.toString.call to print their real type.

Comment: @任劲松 that may be true, but the outcome is still the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17256340/989920