# JavaScript: Which problems can be caused when using the constructor-function of primitive data-types?

Tags: javascript

Many authors state that one should use the literal notation when creating primitive data-types (string, number, boolean).

Means:

```
var demo = '123test'
```

... instead of ...

```
var demo = new String('123test')
```

But no one writes concrete why you should avoid the constructor-function.

Sure. It's more to write but beside that:

Can give me someone an exact example why I shouldn't use the constructor?

Respectively can write me which problems might result from the usage of the constructor?

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-literals-and-string-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Try `typeof demo` with both of your options.