# When does JS create an object wrapper for a string?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Symbol.iterator in 'retularString' // error right-hand side of `in` sould be an object

Symbol.iterator in new String() // true

Does that mean JS creates object wrappers for strings **only** when it calls  methods / or accesses corresponding properties on them like `'string'.toUppercase()` / `'string'.length`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean JS creates object wrappers for strings **only** when it calls  methods / or accesses corresponding properties on them like `'string'.toUppercase()` / `'string'.length`?

Yes.

When you have a string declared as `var foo = 'foo'` its type is the primitive `string`, having no properties inherently, but when you try and access a property on it, the primitive is wrapped momentarily in the `String` object through a process called **implicit coercion**.

See [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839) for a full explanation of coercion in JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question are a good addition: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17256182/10245948

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that's wrapping does not occur upon any other circumstances.