# Switching based on object type

Tags: typescript

If i have a union type, how can i structure control flow to operate on the value as the actual concrete type that it contains?  Sometimes I can do instanceof testing at runtime and then cast it, but that seems both clunky, unsafe, and not always possible (You can't instanceof a typed array).  How can i operate on values safely when the actual type is a union?

In this example below, `food.value` causes a type error.  Is there any way to make the compiler understand this is a {value:string} type without explicit casting?

```
type FoodSet = (string | { value: string })[]

const myValues : FoodSet = [
    "hamburger",
    "cheeseburger",
    {value: "salad"},
    "fish",
    {value: "quinoa"}
]

myValues.forEach(food => {
    if (food instanceof String) {
        console.log(food)
    } else {
        console.log(food.value) // <-- error here
    }
})
```

I'd love something like

```
switch(typeof food) {
    case string:
        console.log(food)
    case {value:string}:
        console.log(food.value)
}
```

Comment: Why not just make all the entries in `myValues` the same? Either a string or an object with a value property.

Answer (score 3):

Your initial attempt is very close! The problem is that `food instanceof String` isn't *quite right*: that would work if `FoodSet` were `(String | { value: string })[]` (note the capital `S`).

To check if `food` is a `string`, you should use `typeof food === "string"` instead. That will correctly narrow the type in the `else` branch to `{ value: string }`:

```js
type FoodSet = (string | { value: string })[]

const myValues : FoodSet = [
    "hamburger",
    "cheeseburger",
    {value: "salad"},
    "fish",
    {value: "quinoa"}
]

myValues.forEach(food => {
    if (typeof food === "string") {
        console.log(food)
    } else {
        console.log(food.value)
    }
})
```

Comment: interesting that made the compiler errors go away, but it also fails, due to what @artem said below, since the primitive strings aren't actually 'String' types.

Answer (score 1):

Javascsript is weird, and TypeScript, by design, does not even try to do anything to improve it at runtime. In Javascript, there are two kind of string values - primitive values and objects ([or boxed strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-primitives-and-string-objects-in-javascrip)).

So you have to check for both, or settle on using only one kind of string throughout the code. Usual recommendation is to avoid using `String` class at all. You can see the difference in javascript console:

```
let primitiveString = 'a';
> 
typeof primitiveString === 'string'
> true  // note that the result of runtime `typeof` is a string
primitiveString instanceof String
> false // primitiveString was not created with the String() constructor, of course
let objectString = new String('a');
>
typeof objectString === 'string'
> false   // typeof objectString returns 'object'
primitiveString instanceof String
> true  
objectString === primitiveString
> false
objectString == primitiveString
> true
```

> I'd love something like

```
switch(typeof food) {
    case string:
        console.log(food)
    case {value:string}:
        console.log(food.value)
}
```

There are two different `typeof` operators in TypeScript.

One is compile-time only, it allows to refer to a type of some variable or function.

Another one is run-time `typeof` which is [the same as in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), and it returns very limited amount of information because TypeScript does not generate any kind of type information available at runtime.

So, every time you want to check a type of the object at runtime, you need to write a series of `if` statements with different kind of checks, as appropriate for the situation:

- `typeof` if you are checking for the kind of built-in type like `string`, `number`, `booelan`, `function` or `object` (`object` basically means "anything else")
- `instanceof` if you want to know which constructor was used to create an object (note that if the value was created as object literal, it will be instance of `Object`, however it may well be compatible with some class because objects literals can have methods too)
- `in` operator if you want to check if an object [has some property or method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- `Array.isArray()` to check if something is an array

and so on.

The compiler detects an error in your code

```
myValues.forEach(food => {
    if (food instanceof String) {
        console.log(food)
    } else {
        console.log(food.value) // <-- error here
    }
})
```

because `instanceof String` will be false for primitive strings, so the `false` branch will be executed trying to access `value` property which does not exists on strings. The usual way to check for a string type is

```
 if (typeof food === 'string') {
```

as explained in another answer.

Comment: wow that primitive vs typed String is incredibly unfortunate.  Changing my instanceof to typeof makes the code work, but also makes the compiler fail again in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

User defined type guards is what i was looking for

```
interface Bird {
    fly();
    layEggs();
}

interface Fish {
    swim();
    layEggs();
}


function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
}

if (isFish(pet)) {
    pet.swim();
}
else {
    pet.fly();
}
```