# How to avoid unnecessary re-rendering of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been learning new features of React 16.8. I believe React's Pure Component should automatically avoid unnecessary re-render operations.

In the following example, the `App` itself is a stateless component. I use `useState` to maintain two state objects `text` and `nested: {text}`.

There are 3 tests. The first 2 tests work. No matter how many times, I change the state, no re-render operation will be required.

Now, the third test tries to set the state of `text` with the same string value, but the reference is different. I expect nothing to be re-rendered, but actually, the `<Headline/>` will be re-rendered.

Shall I use certain memorize technique to avoid? I feel it will be too much code to archive that. And programmer must be very careful to write high-quality React code. ..

```
class Headline extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
   const {text} = this.props;
   return <h1>{text} (render time: {Date.now()})</h1>;
  }
} 

const simpleText = 'hello world'

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(simpleText)
  const [nested, setNested] = React.useState({text: simpleText})
  return (
    <div>
      <Headline text={text}/>
      <Headline text={nested.text}/>

      <button onClick={()=>setText(simpleText)}>
        test 1: the first line should not change (expected)
      </button>

      <button onClick={()=>setNested({text: simpleText})}>
        test 2: the second line will not change  (expected)
      </button>

      <button onClick={()=>setText(new String(simpleText))}>
        test 3: the first line will change on every click (why?)
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Here is a live playground in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fL0psxwo/1/

Thank you React folks, cheers!

---

**Update 1:**
Thanks Dennis for mentioning [why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render)

The author points some very useful articles. I think it could be very educational to everybody.
https://medium.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render-mr-big-pure-react-component-part-2-common-fixing-scenarios-667bfdec2e0f

**Update 2:**
I created a new hook called `withDirtyCheck` so that my code will automatically do content dirty check.

```
import isEqual from 'lodash-es/isEqual';

export const withDirtyCheck = ([getter, setter]) => {
  const setStateIfDirty = (nextState) =>
    setter((prevState) => (isEqual(prevState, nextState) ? prevState : nextState));

  return [getter, setStateIfDirty];
};
```

Checkout my latest library https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/react-einfach

Comment: Where does PureComponent enter into this? Your examples don't include it.

Comment: I need to revise my question. I mean stateless functional component. I thought it equals pure class component. (my bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) you creating a `String Object` which is always different from the previous state.

```
'hello world' === new String('hello world') // false, always.
'hello world' === String('hello world')     // true
```

Check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57078617-stringobject-yo8jf):

```js
setText(prevState => {

  // Will render
  // const currState = new String(simpleText);

  // Won't render
  const currState = String(simpleText);

  console.log(prevState === currState); // if true, no re-render
                                        // if false, re-render

  return currState;
});
```

[image: Edit antd-starter]

Refer to [What is the difference between string primitives and String objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-primitives-and-string-objects-in-javascrip)

Comment: I take your point. I think my major wrong is that, I consider stateless component is same as pure component. But they actually behave quite differently.

Comment: But you know, in a large project, some people (like me) can be wrong to write shitty code. My wish is even if I write something like `new String(...)`, I can still find the problem at static-checking stage, or use some built-in/3rd-party content level dirty checks to help.

Comment: Check [why-did-you-render library](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render).