# Class parameters and formatting

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a way to have class parameter that can be formatted.

```
class Animal {
  this.dob: '2019-12-12';
  // Pseudo code
  format: (date, format) => formatDate(date, format);
}

const animal = new Animal();
```

when calling it: `animal.dob` I want to see `'2019-12-12'`

but if I want it formatted, I'd like to have the option to chain:

`animal.dob.format('DD.MM)` which would return `'12-12'`

My main reason for doing that is that at the moment I have `format(animal.dob, 'DD.MM')` littering my code all over the place and I would like to remove these calls as much as possible.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: tried using `split` and `.join()` ?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: quick question what date format you follow  `yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy/dd/mm` ?

Comment: does it really matter? My question is more about chaining from one parameter than formatting. Here I give the example of date, but I can also have currency, number, percentage, string formatters. But to answer your question: 'yyyy/mm/dd'

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia yes it does to see what should be the expected output, if you notice `animal.dob` will return  a string which doesn't have `format` method attached to it, so you can't chain it like this, Your `animal.dob` should return something which has `format` method

Comment: Have you had a look at object proxies in ES6? Not entirely browser compatible but can be transpiled using Babel.

Comment: Yes @christopher, I tried with Proxies and it works perfectly with Chrome, but IE 11 (which I have to support) is not happy about it. But that was 8 months ago roughly, I might give it another try, with a proper polyfil

Comment: Have you tried using Babel for transpiling your Javascript?

Comment: Yes Babel is there, and transpiling happily :D

Comment: So surely you can transpile that down to an IE11 compatible implementation?

Comment: Didn't work last I tried, but I will give it another go.

Comment: @christopher No, proxies are of no use here, as they cannot wrap primitives

Comment: I wasn't advocating that they wrap the primitive. I was asking if they tried wrapping the object and check when that field is updated. It's not really desirable to tell you the truth, i'd rather stick a method in the class definition than have some hidden proxy logic.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is a bit like the implementation of jQuery. You can do `$(element)` which will return the node you're looking for, OR, you can keep on chaining: `$(element).doSomething()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object from the string and add the `format` method to the instance. The string object can be used as normal string. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256182/what-is-the-difference-between-string-primitives-and-string-objects-in-javascrip) for the differences.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor() {
    this.dob = Object("2019-12-12"); // or new String("...")
    this.dob.format = function (format) {
      console.log(this.valueOf(), format);
    };
  }
}

const animal = new Animal();
animal.dob.format("DD.MM");
```

```
Object("Hello") + Object("World!") //=> "HelloWorld!"
```

If you use certain custom methods often consider creating your own class instead, extending from `String`.

```js
class MyString extends String {
  format(format) {
    console.log(this.valueOf(), format);
  }
}

class Animal {
  constructor() {
    this.dob = new MyString("2019-12-12");
  }
}

const animal = new Animal();
animal.dob.format("DD.MM");
```

If you want to set `dob` after creation, considder adding a `.setDob` method, that accepts a string and converts it to an object with the needed methods. Alternatively you might want to look into [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

> **Note:** You don't need to call `.valueOf()` this converts the string object back to a native string. They behave the same. I only use it here because the console output is nicer. `"foo" //=> "foo"` while `Object("foo") //=> { 0: "f", 1: "o", 2: "o" }`

Comment: ah. thanks for that, I guess that's going in the right direction. Now calling `animal.dob.valueOf()` is a bit cumbersome but not too problematic. I could now have a getter for these computed values...

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia You don't need to, `animal.dob` behaves as a normal string. I only do it here because the `console.log` output is different. eg. `{ 0: "2", 1: "0", 2: "1", ... }`

Comment: interesting. I tried in the console and yes it works well. Does that work with numbers too?

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia yes, see: [`Object()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) - "The `Object` constructor creates an object wrapper."

Comment: Cool, let me try that in my code, if all goes well you'll be the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain `animal.dob.format` like this because your `animal.dob` returns a string which doesn't have any method called `format` on it, Instead what you can do is pass the parameter to `animal.format()` and return values accordingly

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(){
    this.dob = '2019-10-12';
  }
  format(date, format){
    let [YY,MM,DD] = date.split('-')
    let mapper={ YY, MM, DD }
    format = format.replace(/\./g,'-')
    return format.replace(/[^-]+/g,(m)=>mapper[m])
  }
}

const animal = new Animal();

console.log(animal.format(animal.dob, "MM.DD"))
console.log(animal.format(animal.dob, "YY.DD"))
console.log(animal.format(animal.dob, "YY.MM.DD"))
console.log(animal.format(animal.dob, "YY.DD.MM"))
```

If you don't want to pass date explicitly you can simply use `this.dob` instead of accepting a parameter `date` in format function

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(){
      this.dob = '2019-10-12';
    }
    format(date, format){
      let [YY,MM,DD] = this.dob.split('-')
      let mapper={ YY, MM, DD }
      format = format.replace(/\./g,'-')
      return format.replace(/[^-]+/g,(m)=>mapper[m])
   }
}

const animal = new Animal();

console.log(animal.format("MM.DD"))
console.log(animal.format("YY.DD"))
console.log(animal.format("YY.MM.DD"))
console.log(animal.format("YY.DD.MM"))
```

Comment: While this doesn't reduce the boilerplate, it is a more sensible place for the code. It's also nice and clear.

Comment: But it adds code, and absolutely not answer my question. I would rather have a specific method on the class then `animal.formatBOD()`, than implementing that solution

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia well if you don't want to pass the date value explicitly you can simply use `this.dob` inside `format` function, read the last line in the answer isn't it what you're after ?

Comment: but still, my question is about chaining potential formatting, not just the date

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia with the current type of `this.dob` it doesn't seems possible to me as far as i know, you need to change the structure of `this.dob` ? do you want that ?

Comment: yes I can do that, however, if possible, `animal.dob` needs to return a value :D

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia [`Look at this`](https://jsbin.com/kefegiq/edit?js,console) you can do something like this,