# What is the difference between String and new String?

Tags: javascript

Of the many methods to convert to a string, I am confused between:

`var foo = new String(val);`

vs

`var foo = String(val);`

When to use one over the other ?

Comment: Primitive vs object. `new String` is not used. `String` to cast a string yes. Or `''` for anything else.

Comment: @elclanrs could you expand a bit ?

Comment: `typeof new String('foo') == 'object'` and `typeof String('foo') == 'string'`

Comment: @Oriol question is not a duplicate, someone new to javascript does not know that String('a') is not an object,

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects

Comment: More info here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Maybe yes, but the difference between `String` and `new String` is the same as the difference between a primitive [String value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.16) and a [String object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.18), so in that sense they are duplicates. Maybe [Why does (“foo” === new String(“foo”)) evaluate to false in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10951906/1529630) would have been better.