# Why new String("a") == new String("a") returning false and new Number(7) == new Number(7)

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I was just working around with number and string and found Expected behavior of javascript.

```
new String("a") == "a" returns true while new String("a") == new String("a") returns false
```

Same applies with Number

> new Number(7) == new Number(7) returns false

Please Someone explain me why this is happening

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `new String("a") == new String("a")` returns _`false`_?

Comment: `new` creates an Object, every Object occupies its own memory space, so comparing two `objects` will return `false`, in the first case, Object is treated as `string "a"` so its equal with `string literal "a"`

Comment: Another dupe target: [Why does (“foo” === new String(“foo”)) evaluate to false in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10951906/4642212).

Comment: yes @Xufox it returns false