# Adding properties to variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following codes:

```
var str = "abc";
 str.foo = 123;  // write - ignored
123
 str.foo  // read
undefined
```

Why do I get undefined? Shouldn't that property output `123`? What is the reason for it outputting undefined?

Since `var str` is a string, why don't properties show up a second time?

Cant we add properties and methods to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining str as a `string`, not an `object`. Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
var o = {};
o.str = "abc";
o.foo = 123;
```

See the selected answer to this question for lots of great detail:

[Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Comment: str = new String("abc");

Comment: This question is on the way to being closed as a duplicate. see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82420/remove-rep-gained-from-answering-a-question-that-is-a-duplicate for why you shouldn't answer these types of questions.

Comment: @frontendmagic I just deleted a comment questioning why you wrote that, but after a quick test, its quite clear. `typeof new String("abc")` is `object` whereas `typeof "abc"` is `string`. Thanks for the comment!