# Store extra properties in a javascript integer

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Consider this excerpt from a node.js REPL session:

```
> var a = 5;
undefined
> a.b = true;
true
> a.b;
undefined
```

The intention is to store extra properties in `a`, which if successful would make the final line be `true` instead of `undefined`. How can I do this?

Comment: @Bergi arguably not: knowing that the two questions are the same requires knowledge of types in javascript which askers of this question (such as myself) may not have known.

Comment: You're right, [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript/5201148#5201148) might be a better duplicate. Even if I cannot find it, I'm confident there exists a good canonical question already.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. A number is not an object in JavaScript. When you write:

```
a.b = true;
```

what happens is that the runtime instantiates a Number instance automatically. That's an object. You set the "b" property on that object to `true`, and then it's forgotten.

Now, you can do this:

```
var a = new Number(5);
a.b = true;
alert(a.b);
```

and it'll work just fine.