# What does Object(obj) === obj do?

Tags: javascript

different from `obj != null;`

I know that `obj != null` will detect anything that is allowed to have properties on it as null and undefined are the only two values which can not have properties.

How does this differ from

`Object(obj) === obj;`

Comment: The result is not really the same. Take, for instance, a string or number primitive: it is != null but its object boxed counterpart is not === the primitive form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Object(obj) === obj` tests whether `obj` is an object or a primitive, failing also for strings, etc.

```
console.log(Object('foo') === 'foo'); // false
console.log(Object(true) === true);   // false
console.log(Object(null) === null);   // false

var obj = {};
console.log(Object(obj) === obj);     // true
```

It's useful for determining if the value can be given ***and remember*** an assigned property.

While `null` and `undefined` outright error when attempting to use properties, which is why `obj != null` is still useful, [no primitive values are able to hold onto properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript).

```
var pri = 'foo';
pri.foo = 'bar';      // no error, but still...
console.log(pri.foo); // undefined

var box = Object(pri);
box.foo = 'bar';
console.log(box.foo); // 'bar'
```

---

Reference:

When `obj` is `null` or `undefined`, [`Object(obj)` returns a `new Object()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.1.1):

> 1) If *value* is `null`, `undefined` or not supplied, create and return a new Object object exactly as if the standard built-in Object constructor had been called with the same arguments ([15.2.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1)).

And, primitive booleans, strings, and numbers are boxed into their object types via [`ToObject()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9), which are not equal to their primitive equivalents:

> 2) Return [ToObject](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9)(*value*).

```
console.log(typeof 'foo' === 'string');         // true
console.log(typeof Object('foo') === 'object'); // true

console.log('foo' instanceof String);           // false
console.log(Object('foo') instanceof String);   // true
```

Answer (score -3):

Identity (===. !==)

These operators behave identically to the equality operators except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm

Nice Stack overflow link
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This is not just about != and !==, rather it is `x != null` and `Object(x) === x`

Comment: First link gives the basic JS operator meaning and second link (SO) answers explains much better. Those two links gave me convincing answer to the problem.