# Strings are not object then why do they have properties?

Tags: javascript

Code like this:

```
var str = "Hello StackOverflow !";
alert(typeof str);
```

gives me `string` as result. This means strings are not objects, **then why do we have properties of a string `str` like `str.substring`, `str.indexOf etc.?`**
Also when i set property to it as

`str.property = "custom property is set";` and trying to get this `alert(str.property)`, it gives me `undefined`. Why?

Comment: If `String` isn't an `Object`, then why does `String.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype` give `true`?

Comment: The same reason that `12.toString()` works, even though numbers aren't objects.

Comment: so if they behaves as objects. then why can't i set property to them ? Also, typeof should return object, its misleading.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5201138/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string like "Hello" is not an object in JavaScript, but when used in an expression like

```
"Hello".indexOf(2)
```

A new object derived from the constructor function `String` is produced wrapping the string `"Hello"`.  And `indexOf` is a property of `String.prototype` so things work as expected, even though there is a lot of magic going on.

In the following case

```
> var s = "xyz"; s.prop = 1; console.log(s.prop);
undefined
```

The reason you see `undefined` is that:

1. The variable `s` is given a value which is a primitive string
2. In `s.prop = 1` and property named `prop` is assigned to a new, anonymous wrapper object.
3. In the third statment above, another new object is created to wrap the primitive `s`.  That is not the same wrapper object as in the second statement, and it does not have a `prop` property, so `undefined` is produced when asking for its value according to the basic JavaScript rules.

Comment: +1 for the extra explanation about the anonymous wrapper objects.

Comment: cool.got it.  so the temporary object(wrapper) is created as if by calling new String(str), when u trying to access the property.

Answer (score 6):

### **Is string an object?**

This depends on how you defines *object* and what are you referring to when you say *string*. When you use the word string, you can be referring to just the primitive, or the [wrapper object](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/wrapper-objects).

### **What are primitives**?

In JavaScript there are 5 primitive types: undefined, null, boolean, string and number. Everything else is an object.

Unlike objects, primitives don't really have properties. They exist as values. This explains why you cannot assign a property to a string:

```
var archy = "hello";
archy.say = "hello";
console.log(archy.say); // undefined
```

But sometimes manipulating a primitive would make one feel as if she/he is manipulating an object because primitives appear to have methods.

```
var archy = "hello";
console.log(archy.length); //5
```

This is due to the fact that JavaScript creates a [wrapper object](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/wrapper-objects) when you attempt to access any property of a primitive.

### **What are wrapper objects**?

Here is an extract from [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-3/wrapper-objects)

> The temporary objects created when you access a property of a string,
>   number, or boolean are known as wrapper objects, and it may
>   occasionally be necessary to distinguish a string value from a String
>   object or a number or boolean value from a Number or Boolean object.
>   Usually, however, wrapper objects can be considered an implementation
>   detail and you don’t have to think about them. You just need to know
>   that string, number, and boolean values differ from objects in that
>   their properties are read-only and that you can’t define new
>   properties on them.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are pure objects: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5

So the question is, what does the `typeof` operator. It simply acts according to its ECMA specification:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Answer (score 2):

Strings are actually a special kind of objects. You can't add properties to them, but you can modify the `String.prototype`, which is the prototype of any `string` variable, and add properties to it, like this:

```
String.prototype.foo = 1;
var a = 'hello';
console.log(a.foo); // logs 1
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a prototype base language and you can define properties for your variables. Strings also have their predefined properties and methods to be used.

[more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)