# Why is `s.len` undefined (and not 4) while `s` has the value `test`? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am puzzled with this one. I have the following code.

```
var s = "test";
s.len = 4;
var t = s.len;
```

The question is why the variable `t` has a value of `undefined`.

If you check the `s.len` after that code it is undefined.
If you check `s` the value is `test`. Not sure what is going on here. I am sure there is an explanation, but can't get my head around that and don't know how to search that.

For those who consider to vote down. This is a question we got in a course, and we are expected to prepare for the next session with this *riddle*.
I am not new to programming, but I fail to research how JavaScripts treats this code. It is valid code really, execute it in your Dev Tools and you will see.

I define a property for the string s called len assign to it the value 4. This property is, I believe created, but undefined. I would like to now why is it ? Is it specific to strings in JavaScript ?

Comment: `.length`, not `.len`

Comment: You assign `s.len=4` this is posible only when `s` is a object and `len` is the part of `s` .

Comment: If you wanted to get lenght of string `s` just use `s.lenght`. Why do you assign the value `4` to the string lenght ?

Comment: It is a question we got to prepare and research how objects and so on are treated in JavaScript. @Sachink

Comment: Please let us konw what you want to do with JavaScript. We will help you.

Comment: I define a property for the string `s` called `len` assign to it the value 4. This property is, I believe created, but undefined. I would like to now why is it ?
Is it specific to strings in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I fail to research how JavaScripts treats this code.

That is easy: strings are primitive types in JS, which means they don't have properties by themselves.

For `.` operator to work with them (e.g. for `.length` call) javascript defines such a thing called "wrapper objects".

So when you try to access a property of a primitive object - a temporary *wrapper object* is created that does behave as an object, hence you can access and assign properties to it.

The problem is that the wrapper object is temporary, so after it's used to access a property the object is discarded with all its state.

That's why when you assign a `.len` property you cannot access it on the next line: it's lost.

So a pseudo code for what actually happens behind the scenes for your code is

```
var s = "test";
(new String(s)).len = 4; // here you add an attribute for a new object
                         // and `s` is left untouched
var t = s.len;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The question is why the variable t has a value of undefined.

Because you have defined `s` as a string not as an object. so `s.len` should be `undefined`!

I am not sure what are you trying to do. But if you want to get the `length` of `s` then `t = s.length` will simply work.

> I define a property for the string s called len assign to it the value 4. This property is, I believe created, but undefined. I would like to now why is it ? Is it specific to strings in JavaScript ?

You can find the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a new property to string?

Comment: you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript @Elyasin

Comment: Perfect answer @hasan3050. Add this to your answer and I accept it right away. That is exactly the explanation I was trying to find. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer. However I accepted zerkms answer as it is concise and clear. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

run :

```
var s1 = "test";
console.log(typeof s1)//string
var s2 = {}
console.log(typeof s2)//object
s1.len = 4;
s2.len = 4;
console.log(s1.len);//undefine
console.log(s2.len);//4
```

Comment: Thank you Harden. This raises a question. If strings are not objects, then I wonder they can have properties.

Comment: primitive types also called simple data type