# how to find the props in obj with variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am passing my string to the below function.

```
$scope.sort= function(query){
    console.log(query); // results "name";

    $scope.resultset.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b.query) - parseFloat(a.query);  //results undefined;
    });
};
```

where `b` and `a` are my objects in resultset Array.

How to find the props in obj with variable name?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` string objects?.. You cannot append dynamic properties to strings in javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5201148/2300466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean accessing an object property with a dynamic name.

In javascript, you can access any object propert with an array-like notation:

```
b.query
```

is equivalent to :

```
b["query"]
```

So you could do :

```
var property = "query";
var value = b[property];
```