# Can I have an object key as part of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I am trying to sort some numbers, and I want to count the number of times that an array has a certain number.

My question is more about the structure of an the array than the counting the number part. I would like to build an array that looks like this below.

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];
```

How could I make the data structure below?

`numbers[3].count // this will be equal to 3 after I loop through;`

How do I make each part of the array have an object parameter?

Do I just loop through like so?

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  numbers[i] = {
    count: 0
  }
}
```

I understand this wont give me the right count, but I don't care about that part of the problem. I would like to solve that on my own. I just need to be sure that this is the correct way to add the object parameters.

Comment: Yes, that seems a fine solution, though you'll want to store the value at the index in the object as well as othewise you'll just be overwriting it. So `numbers[i] = {value: numbers[i], count: 0};`

Comment: Keep in mind that you're not adding keys to the array, but making each element of the array an object which has keys. `[{count: 0}, {count: 0}]`

Comment: Right, that is what I want to do. But from your first comment are you saying that if I ran that code as is then, numbers[0] would be equal to 0?

If so, How can I get it so that numbers[0] = 1 and numbers[0].count = 0

Comment: @AlexBarbosa A value in JavaScript cannot simultaneously be multiple types (e.g. `number` and `object`). Any value that has properties in JavaScript is an `object`. If you want to store multiple values (e.g. a value and a count), you'd need to store them on properties of an object (or as elements in a sub-array).

Comment: @AlexBarbosa You can initialize a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) outside the loop, and store the information about each array element as you iterate. And you can do all of this inside a [reducer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which returns the map.

Comment: The post [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5201138/6831341) provides some interesting insight into the problem you are facing.  [This answer discusses using the type constructor to achieve something to this affect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5326882/6831341)-- you could probably do something similar with `new Number()`, but then you'd be stuck leveraging the `.valueOf()` method to get the number back out, and it wouldn't be very idiomatic JS, so I'm not sure if it is really an elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would build these functions on my own. Something like this
You can copy and paste this in the console of your browser.

```
// my numbers list
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6];
// reduced to unique entries
const uniques = [...new Set(numbers)];
// function to count occurrences in my list of number
const count = (n) => numbers.filter((num) => num === n).length;
// you can test here
console.log(`counting ${uniques[4]}s`, count(uniques[4]));
// get these as object
console.log(uniques.map((unique) => ({[unique]: count(unique)})))
```

Comment: or `console.log(uniques.map((unique) => ({[unique]: {count: count(unique)}})))`

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to achieve this by using [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];

const obj = {};

numbers.forEach((item) => {
    obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];
 
const counts = {};

numbers.forEach((x) => counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1);

console.log(counts)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Array#reduce()` method to group elements together into sub arrays. Since arrays have a `length` property that gives the the number of elements this can be applied to each group of like elements. We do not need to create a new `count` property.

```js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];

const freq = numbers.reduce(
    (acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur]:(acc[cur] || []).concat(cur)})
);

console.log( freq[4] );
console.log( freq[4].length );
```

Alternatively, you can put the numbers in an object and get all the unique elements, then for each unique element define a get property that groups like elements together using the `Array#filter()` method. Again, the `length` array property can be used to return the number of elements for each unique element.

```js
const o = {numbers: [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6]};
o.uniq = [...new Set(o.numbers)];
o.uniq.forEach(n => Object.defineProperty(
    o,n,{get:() => o.numbers.filter(num => num === n)}
));
console.log( o[5] );
console.log( o[5].length );
```

Answer (score -2):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is perfect for these kinds of problems.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];

const countedObject = numbers.reduce((tmpObj, number) => {
  if (!tmpObj[number]) {
    tmpObj[number] = 1;
  } else {
    tmpObj[number] += 1;
  }
  return tmpObj
}, {});


console.log(countedObject);
```

if you feel the need to nest it further you can of course do this.
But if `count` is the only property you need, I'd suggest sticking to the first version.

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6];

const countedObject = numbers.reduce((tmpObj, number) => {
  if (!tmpObj[number]) {
    tmpObj[number] = {count: 1};
  } else {
    tmpObj[number].count += 1;
  }
  return tmpObj
}, {});


console.log(countedObject);
```