# Getting a value from a named key in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to get a specific value by supplying the literal key in a javascript object.  In the image below you see that "filter" is equal to "Approved".  This is coming from reimb_status_description in the image below.

Line 6 of the code is where I assign filter to the value.

```
const filter = Object.values(jsonData[i]["reimb_status_description"]).join("");
```

What I do not understand is that if I did not end with `.join("")`, filter would read as "A,p,p,r,o,v,e,d" which is apparently an array of the letters.  Could someone please help me understand why the result is an array instead of just a string?  Also, is there a better method of extracting the data I am looking for?

[image]

```
function PopulateReimbursementTable(jsonData, appliedFilter)
{
    ClearReimbursementTable();

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
    {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");
        const entries = Object.entries(jsonData[i])

        const filter = Object.values(jsonData[i]["reimb_status_description"]).join("");
        console.log("filter: " + filter)
        for(const [key, property] of entries)
        {
            if(fields.includes(key)){
                console.log(key + "\t" + property);
                const td = document.createElement("td");
                if(key == "reimb_date_submitted" || key == "reimb_date_resolved"){
                    if(property == null)
                    {
                        td.innerHTML = "tbd";
                    }else{
                        var d = new Date(property);
                        let formatted_date = appendLeadingZeroes((d.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + appendLeadingZeroes(d.getDate()) + "-" + d.getFullYear();
                        //console.log(formatted_date)
                        td.innerHTML = formatted_date;
                    }
                } else if(key == 'reimb_amount'){
                    if(property === null || property === undefined)
                    {
                        td.innerHTML = "tbd";
                    }else{
                        td.innerHTML = formatter.format(property);
                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    if(property === null || property === undefined)
                    {
                        td.innerHTML = "tbd";
                    }else{
                        td.innerHTML = property;
                    }               
                }

                if(fields.includes(key))
                {
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
            }

        }

        if(appliedFilter == "All"){
            reimbTableBody.appendChild(tr);
        }
        else if(filter == appliedFilter){
            reimbTableBody.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jsonData[i]["reimb_status_description"]` is a *string*, so if you do `Object.values` on it, it would be treated as an array and thus you get the values of said array.

Comment: I'd suggest to learn about filter, map and reduce funtions, they're very helpful. I like this post https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `Object.values` does with a `String`<sup>**1**</sup>. So in your case I think you can use `jsonData[i].reimb_status_description` to retrieve the string value.

<sup>**1**</sup> Why? Because a string is actually a one-dimensional array with elements of the type character.

```js
console.log(Object.values("some string"));

// this would deliver the string though
console.log(Object.values({someString: "some string"})[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Yes, I just  updated the code with that and it is giving the results I was looking for.  I was too focused on the whole Object.entries(jsonData[i]) that I failed to realize that jsonData[i] is in JSON notation.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN doc:

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable property values

It seems that `jsonData[i]["reimb_status_description"]` returns string. Any values passed to `Object.values` is converted to object. String primitive type can be converted to String  array-like object ([here more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156196/are-strings-objects)) in javascript. So when you pass string to `Object.values` it's converted to array-like object which values are individual characters. So in such case `Object.values` returns an array with individual characters of given string.